# How to set the value of local variable inside else loop in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to do a select from multiple tables and some of the columns values will be based on the case like this (the statement in else loop is giving error)

```
(select case 
when @caQuoteIdTemp = corporateQuotes.caQuoteID
    then @randomNumber
else (set @caQuoteIdTemp = corporateQuotes.caQuoteID ) 
end )as costmoney
```

here `@caQuoteIdTemp` and `@randomNumber` are local variables I declared like this -

```
DECLARE @randomNumber      FLOAT
declare @caQuoteIdTemp int
set @randomNumber = convert(numeric(15,0),rand() * 899999999999999) + 100000000000000
set @caQuoteIdTemp = 1
```

Now my questions is: how can I set the value of `@caQuoteIdTemp` to `@caQuoteIdTemp = corporateQuotes.caQuoteID` in the else statement?

At the moment I am getting syntax error. I am wondering if it is not at all possible to change the value of a variable

EDIT:::

The full Query is like this

```
    DECLARE @randomNumber      FLOAT
declare @caQuoteIdTemp int
set @randomNumber = convert(numeric(15,0),rand() * 899999999999999) + 100000000000000
set @caQuoteIdTemp = 1

select
corporateQuotes.caQuoteID, 
prod_sub.ProdID,
corporateQuoteItems.prodSubID,
prod.publisherID,
prod.Title,
prod.code,
corporateQuotes.date_ordered,
(select DATEPART(WK, corporateQuotes.date_ordered)) as week_ordered,
(select DATEPART(MONTH, corporateQuotes.date_ordered)) as month_ordered,
(select DATEPART(YEAR, corporateQuotes.date_ordered)) as year_ordered,
prod_sub.[length],
prod_sub.issues,
prod_sub.extra_info,
-- cost money --
(select case 
    when corporateQuotes.discountIsPoundValue = 1
        then prod_sub.your_price + prod_sub.commission - corporateQuotes.discount
    else (prod_sub.your_price + prod_sub.commission - (corporateQuotes.discount * prod_sub.your_price/100)) 
    end as costmoney)as costmoney,  
corporateAccounts.companyName,
-- saving money --
(prod_sub.rrp * prod_sub.issues - prod_sub.your_price )as savingmoney,
corporateAccounts.title,
corporateAccounts.firstName,
corporateAccounts.lastName,
corporateAccounts.street,
corporateAccounts.suburb,
corporateAccounts.[state],
corporateAccounts.postcode,
corporateAccounts.country,
corporateAccounts.phone,

-- Do something about TransID here--
(select @caQuoteIdTemp =(
    case 
        when @caQuoteIdTemp = corporateQuotes.caQuoteID
            then @randomNumber
        else corporateQuotes.caQuoteID
     as test) ,

@randomNumber as st_transId,

prod_sub.start_issue,
prod_sub.effort_code,
prod_sub.premium_code,
--do something about commison --
-- discount applied --
(select 
    case 
        when corporateQuotes.discountIsPoundValue = 1
            then corporateQuotes.discount
        else (corporateQuotes.discount * prod_sub.your_price/100) 
        end as discountApplied)as discountApplied,

-- pending orderID --

 --PP transID -- 
 -- commison  --
 corporateQuotes.commission,

 corporateQuotes.discount

from corporateQuotes
join corporateQuoteItems on
corporateQuotes.caQuoteID = corporateQuoteItems.caQuoteID
join corporateAccounts on 
corporateQuotes.caID = corporateAccounts.caID
join prod_sub on
corporateQuoteItems.prodSubID = prod_sub.ProdSubID
join prod on
prod_sub.ProdID = prod.ProdID

where corporateQuotes.orderId is null
--group by corporateQuotes.caQuoteID
order by corporateQuotes.caQuoteID
;
```

Comment: You cannot do this inside a `CASE` - in T-SQL, the `CASE` **only** returns a single value - it's **not** intended to control program flow; for that, you need to use `IF .... THEN .... ELSE ....`  blocks

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a select statement but in the else part all you are doing is setting a variable. I'm assuming you want to select @randomNumber if the Id's match otherwise just reset the variable in which case why not use an IF...ELSE... e.g.

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM corporateQuotes WHERE @caQuoteIdTemp = corporateQuotes.caQuoteID))
    SELECT  @randomNumber AS costmoney
ELSE
    SET @caQuoteIdTemp = corporateQuotes.caQuoteID
```

Comment: Thanks Bob. I tried that and it is giving me error :
the multi part identifier "corporateQuotes.caQuoteID " could not be bound. and it is also saying that there is a syntax error near if statement

Comment: Ok, thats because table corporateQuotes wasn't included in the query. I've edited my answer, although I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want to achieve - could i suggest you include the whole sql statement in your question, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But i still don't follow the logic - it looks like the statement is selecting potentially multiple rows (where orderId is null) and if it finds a matching row where @ caQuoteIdTemp = caQuoteId it resets @caQuoteIdTemp to a random number oetherwise it sets @ caQuoteIdTemp to caQuoteId (in the original question anyway) which doesn't make sense if potentially multiple rows are being matched. Is the variable needed? - presumably it's referenced later on in the SQL batch which is not shown. Sorry can't help further unless I know what your trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @randomNumber      FLOAT
declare @caQuoteIdTemp int
set @randomNumber = convert(numeric(15,0),rand() * 1000) + 1000
set @caQuoteIdTemp = 1

select @caQuoteIdTemp =(case when @caQuoteIdTemp = corporateQuotes.caQuoteID
    then @randomNumber
    else corporateQuotes.caQuoteID
                        end ) from corporateQuotes

SELECT @caQuoteIdTemp as costmoney
```

i have reduced the range for random number, previous values were causing arithmetic overflow.

Comment: You are not setting the value of '@caQuoteIdTemp' to '@caQuoteIdTemp =corporateQuotes.caQuoteID'.

Comment: Sorry I missed that part. Well I have updated the query in my question but it is still giving me syntax error. Can you please point out the mistake there

Comment: Please mark as answer if this has resolved your problem